# Location.geocodeAsync() in react native expo (manage workflow) returns an empty list on Android because of timeout issue

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have been trying to get the latitude and longitude of the address `location` using `Location.geocodeAsync()`. It works completely fine on iOS but not Android.

This my function that converts address into latitude and longitude. However,   `console.log(geocodedLocation);` returns an empty list because of `timeout` issue.

```
  const geocode = async () => {
    try {
      const geocodedLocation = await Location.geocodeAsync(location);
      console.log(geocodedLocation);
      const res = {
        latitude: geocodedLocation[0].latitude,
        longitude: geocodedLocation[0].longitude,
      };
      return res;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationgeocodeasyncaddress-options), I will have to do this: ***On Android, you must request a location permission (Permissions.LOCATION) from the user before geocoding can be used.***

Therefore, I have done this using `Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync` in the useEffect as well.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getPermissions = async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        console.log("Please grant location permissions");
        return;
      } else {
        console.log("permission granted");
      }

      let currentLocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});

      const latitude = currentLocation.coords.latitude;
      const longitude = currentLocation.coords.longitude;
      console.log(latitude, longitude);
      setInitialRegion({
        latitude: latitude ?? 0,
        longitude: longitude ?? 0,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      });
    };

    getPermissions();
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

However, it still does not work at all.

- I have tried to grant permission using `(Permissions.LOCATION)` but expo stated it is deprecated.
- I have even grant location permission using `requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync`.